# Optimum point on the circumference of a circle

Tags: computational-geometry, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to write a code to find an optimum point along the circumference of a circle.

Say there is a circle defined in 3D space, such that I know its radius and the plane that it lies on. I also know the location of the centre of the circle.

I also have a point outside of this circle, and I know its 3D location. I want to find the point on the circumference of the circle that is closest to this outside point.

What is the most efficient way to compute this?

Comment: You need more than the radius and the plane, you also need the location of the center.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I know the center location as well. I've edited the question to include this.

Comment: Is the point outside the circle on the same plane as the circle?

Comment: The point is not necessarily on the same plane, it can be anywhere in 3D space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Analytic solution**:

First: Make a projection of your point to the plane the circle lies in: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection). This way the problem gets 2D.

Second: Draw a line between the prjection and the center of the circle. Where you cross the circumference you have your point

**Mathematical Optimization Solution:**

Select three optional points on the circumference of your circle and calculate each distance to your point. Take the two point with the smaller distance.

Then take a new third point that lies axactly between these two points (on the circumference) and calculate it's distance to your point.

Do this until you have a point that is close enough.

Comment: Uh, that optimization solution is likely to be much slower than the analytic solution.  Because once the problem is 2d, all you need is the angle from the center to the point (`atan(centery, centerx, pointy, pointx)`), and then the answer is `(centerx+radius*cos(angle), centery+radius*sin(angle))`

Comment: Yes for sure. Just wanted to add it because the question was tagged mathematical-optimization.